# Suppress Interactive.jl / Reactive.jl signal info in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook

I`m using Jupyter Notebook in combination with Interactive.jl / Reactive.jl .

When I`m using @manipulate with a slider and afterwards rerun the block of code I see these info/warning messages highlighted in red:

```
[Input{Int64}] 180
[Input{Int64}] 210
[Input{Int64}] 255
[Input{Int64}] 180
[Input{Int64}] 210
[Input{Int64}] 135
```

Any idea on what causes these messages? How to suppress them?

The specific code I used was

```
function complex_round(complex_number,digits_after_comma)
    return round(real(complex_number),digits_after_comma) + round(imag(complex_number),digits_after_comma)*im
end

@manipulate for θ in 0:15:360, ϕ in 0:15:360 # let us manipulate the value of θ

    psi = [cosd(θ/2),e^(2*pi*im*ϕ/360)*sind(θ/2)]
    rho = complex_round(kron(psi',psi),3)
    psi = complex_round(psi,3)

    # Some very annoying hack required to make the print
    # I will look into Compose/Cairo.
    text = Array(Any,(2,6))

    # text[row,column]
    text[1,1] = "psi"
    text[2,1] = "="
    text[1:2,2] = psi

    text[1,3] = "|" 
    text[2,3] = "|"

    text[1,4] = "rho"
    text[2,4] = "="

    text[1:2,5:6] = rho    

    text
end
```

Help is much appreciated!